# Attribute query in ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, query

I am trying to export a specific part of a dataset, based on an attribute query.

My dataset has a field *REGION*

[image]

and I would like to select all features where the region is equal to 2.

Here is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "esri shapefile" -clipdstwhere "REGION = 2" africa.shp world.shp
```

[image]

Although an output is created it is an exact copy of the original. In other words, the query does not keep the command from running but it is not correctly executed nevertheless.

I have tried different variations (putting REGION in double quotes and escaping them etc., but I am unable to get it to work).

Comment: I do not know how -clipdstwhere is supposed to be used but for your use case `-where REGION=2`should work. Clipdstwhere seems to require another layer for queries "When specifying a datasource, you will generally want to use it in combination of the -clipdstlayer, -clipdstwhere or -clipdstsql options" and it is made for clipping features, not for simple selection. Another option is to use -sql for making the selection.

Comment: This worked fine! I was just looking for a command to query before exporting, so this answers my question. No need to use -clipdstwhere then; that was just the command I came upon. Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted!